# How to show data from two tables php mysql by avoiding repeats?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is what i am doing I have two tables one is categories and other is softwares

**Category table Looks like this**

```
cid      name
1        Anti-malware
```

**And Software Table looks like this**

```
id       title     catid
1        Avast        1
```

And catid is equal cid you can say that catid is id of category

here is my current code

```
 require('config/db.php');
 $cateq="SELECT * FROM softwares A INNER JOIN categories B ON A.catid=B.cID "; 
  $cateresult=mysql_query($cateq);


    define('MAX_TITLES_PER_CAT',5);

    $cat='';
    $tcount=0;
    while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($cateresult)){
                    $title=$row['title'];
                    $softid=$row['id'];
                    $cateid=$row['cid'];
                    $check_pic = "admin/images/icons/".$softid."/image01.jpg";

                    if (file_exists($check_pic)) {
                          $icon = "<img src=\"$check_pic\" class=\"home_icon\"    />"; 
                             } else {
                              $icon = "<i class=\"icon-archive\"></i>"; 
                               }

                    if ($row['name']!=$cat) {

                            if ($cat!='') echo '</div>';
                             $cat=$row['name'];
                               $tcount=MAX_TITLES_PER_CAT;
                                echo "<div class=\"widget white_box\"><h3 class=\"widget_title\"><a href=\"categories.php?cid=$cateid\">".$cat." <i class=\"icon-chevron-right\"></i></a></h3><ul>";
                                }


                      if ($tcount--<=0) continue;
                      echo '<li>'.$icon.' <a href=\'software-profile.php?pid='.$softid.'\'>'.$title.'</a></li>';


                       }  
                    if ($cat!='') echo '</ul></div>';
```

and here are the results what i am getting 
http://postimg.org/image/d7zn2k6ev/full/
its repeating certain categories in different divs instead of showing in same div all the results.

Comment: The issue might be solved by sorting the data: `SELECT * FROM softwares A INNER JOIN categories B ON A.catid=B.cID ORDER BY B.cID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you parse your query results, you assume the rows are sorted by category (`if ($row['name']!=$cat)`), but no order is guaranteed without an `ORDER BY` clause.

Add `ORDER BY name` to the end of your query.